# Adapters ignored when testing resources in Neo4j unmanaged extension

Tags: java, neo4j

I have implemented an `EntityResource` class with an `Entity` model and `EntityAdapter` adapter overriding [XmlAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) in my Neo4J managed extension. All works well when deploying to the server. The model uses the adapter to marshal the entity and the resource responds accordingly.

However in my test class (below) which uses the Neo4J harness and Neo4JRule the `EntityAdapter` is completely ignored so I receive a default marshaled version of the `Entity` with unwanted values.

```
@Rule
public Neo4jRule neo4j = new Neo4jRule()
        .withFixture( "CREATE ({name:'test'})" )
        .withExtension( "/test", EntityResource.class );


@Test
public void testRead() {
    // Given
    URI serverURI = neo4j.httpURI();

    String uri = serverURI.toString() + "test/entities/test";
    HTTP.Response response = HTTP.GET( uri );

    // Then it should reply
    assertEquals( response.toString(), 200, response.status() );
    System.out.println( response.toString() );

}
```

The adapter must be set up correctly for it to work in the resource so I would guess it's something to do with how the test searches for the correct adapter. My class declaration is below anyway

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter( EntityAdapter.class )
public class Entity {
```

Why isn't the test using the adapter when the server is and how do I fix it?

Comment: just a rough shoot from the hip: do you have http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-xc/1.9.13 on the classpath? This jar is not part of Neo4j distribution.

Comment: It's in my gradle and intellij iml file but it's difficult to tell whether it's actually being used.